# How to Call report click on hyperlink in jasperreport

Tags: jasper-reports

I am facing hyperlink problem, please give me any successfull solution.
How to Call report when click on hyperlink in jasperreport.

```
<textField isBlankWhenNull="true" hyperlinkType="ReportExecution"> 
<reportElement x="270" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="04829694-6fbb-44ef-9ffd-80aa1428c822"/> 
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ESTADO}]]></textFieldExpression> 
<hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
<![CDATA["/home/satlevivek/Desktop/jasperfinal‌​pdf/finalmonday/report2.jasper"]]>
</hyperlinkReferenceExpression> 
</textField>
```

I want click on textfield and open `'/home/satlevivek/Desktop/jasperfinalpdf/finalmonday/report2.jasper'`

Comment: do u mean hyperlink in your web application?

Comment: No, in my jasperreport .
hyperlink and click on that link open another report with passing parameter.please help me

Comment: Please post your code that call the hyperlink.

Comment: I have create one report in jaspersoft ireport and display data like:


ID|Name|Hyperlink 
------------------------
1|test|showinfo
2|test1|showinfo

here i want take showinfo(hyperlink) and click on showinfo open new report in jaspersoft tool.
is it clear now?

Comment: Please post a part of your Jasper code to generate the link in the question. I cant help with this limited information.

Comment: <textField isBlankWhenNull="true" hyperlinkType="ReportExecution">
    <reportElement x="270" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="04829694-6fbb-44ef-9ffd-80aa1428c822"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ESTADO}]]></textFieldExpression>
    <hyperlinkReferenceExpression><![CDATA["/home/satlevivek/Desktop/jasperfinalpdf/finalmonday/report2.jasper"]]></hyperlinkReferenceExpression>
   </textField>

I want click on textfield and open '/home/satlevivek/Desktop/jasperfinalpdf/finalmonday/report2.jasper'